# Listview in a webpart: popup only appear once

Tags: web-part, front-end

**The problem**

I am having a problem, with a Listview that gets included in a Webpart.

When I am trying to make a, action on a list item, I get the dropdown. If I let et close and try to open it again nothing happens.

I don't get a error, and it is testing in IE7->8, FF and Chrome.

The webparts are included like this:

```
<table class="cols-table">
    <tr>
        <td class="cols cols-3">
            <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Top" Title="loc:left">
                <ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
            </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cols cols-3">
            <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Bottom" Title="loc:Left">
                <ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
            </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the gridview:

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView runat="server" ID="gvKurser">
</SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

I don't know where to look, to find a solution to this bug, it would be nice if you could give me a pointer. If you need anymore infomation just let me know, and I'll try to provide it.

**Screenshot**

Here is a screenshot, that show the dropdown/popup:

[image: The red box is marking the dropdown that only gets showed once]
Hope I explained this well, it is a hard one.

Comment: Are there any custom scripts running on the page, or is the masterpage customized?

Comment: Yes. I have included jQuery, and some of my own scripts. They don't give any errors but jQuery might overwrite something in SP. I'll check!

Comment: An obvious test would be to remove the custom scripts one at a time and see if the issue persists...

Comment: No problem there, I still have the issue with no custom scripts and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a JavaScript error. In IE8 go to the page and press F12 to open the Developer Tools window, click the Script tab and make sure the 'Break on Error' button is depressed (it looks like a pause icon with a cross in a red circle) then click the 'Start Debugging' button. Recreate your problem and if it is a JS error the script execution should break at the point the error occurs. If this is the case post some further error details if you need additional help.

Comment: It is not a Javascript error, I checked this in all browsers. I don't get any errors at all.